# Any elegant way to judge whether an int is assigned a value in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

It is common that I want to judge an `int` is assigned or not.

Example code below:

```
int a;
// some pre-codes...
if (a is not assgined) ... not assigned operation
else ... assigned operation

// I tried to do that with code below:
if (a == NULL) ... not assigned operation
else ... assigned operation
```

The problem is that, if `a` is assigned `0` in pre-codes, not assigned operation is still excuted.

At present, I have to set an extra `assigned_flag` of `bool` to check whether `a` is assigned.

Any more elegant method?

Comment: Don't write code where it's not known whether a variable has a value. Declare variables as close to first use as practical. Initialize them.

Comment: I would recommend [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) for this if you really need it.  If you don't initialize it, it has a "null" state and you can check for that.

Comment: Pretty sure, this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem,info). What are you ultimately trying to accomplish? Can you show real code that highlights, why you think that this were necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language does not provide a sentinel value to indicate whether an `int` has  been assigned to or not.

You have the choice of doing that. For example, you can use INT_MAX as a sentinel value if you are very sure that your variable will not be assigned such a value in normal execution.

If you have the option of using C++17, you can use [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional).

You can use a `std::pair<bool, int>` as a poor man's version of `std::optional` with the understanding that the `first` of the pair is initialized to `false` when the `second` of the pair has not been assigned a value. At the time a value is assigned to the `second` of the pair, you'll have to change the `first` to `true` and never change it back.

```
std::pair <bool, int> a{false};

// some pre-codes...
if (a.first == false )
{
    ... not assigned operation
}

else
{
    ... assigned operation
}
```

Comment: `std::pair` is agood solution if you don’t have access to a real `optional`. But I suggest putting the `int` first and the `bool` second to be consistent with the standard library (see for example `std::map::insert()`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in function that checks if an `int` variable has been initialized or assigned a value. It is your responsibility to keep track and initialize variables prior to using them. The compiler might or might not warn you about such eventualities.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is an `int` and can only store integers.  You either will need an extra variable to keep track of whether it has been explicitly assigned, need to reserve a sentinel value that you will never allow to be a validly assigned value (e.g. `INT_MAX`, `INT_MIN`), or you will need to wrap your `int` in an object (e.g `std::optional`) that keeps track for you (by maintaining an extra flag internally).